# How to update Apache,PHP,Open SSL in Sun Solaris 11.2?

Tags: php, apache, openssl, solaris

I want to update the Apache, PHP, OpenSSL to fix the Vulnerabilities which was found in VA scan report. The production server OS is Sun Solaris 11.2, I checked the official documentation but there were not enough information about an openssl update.

There were some information about how to update Php and Apache. Can you please someone guide me how to update above three packages safely? I will be fixing the vulnerabilities in the testbed first. After that I will apply the fix in production.

Comment: Also see [Noloader | Build Scripts](https://github.com/noloader/Build-Scripts). I use them for cURL, Git, Wget and a few others on platforms that are abandoned and ransomed. Apache and PHP should be easy enough to add. I know PHP is not that bad because I built it a few times from sources. I don't know about Apache.

Comment: "I don't know about Apache" - You mean you don't know about openssl isn't it?

Comment: What I meant was, I've never built Apache from sources, so I'm not sure how {easy|hard} it will be. I'm guessing it is just like any other package, like cURL, Git, SSH or Wget.

Comment: Thanks, Any idea How I can install openssl?

Comment: There is a script for OpenSSL in the Build-Scripts. Run the script. Or, open the script, look at everything it does, and manually do the same in your terminal. Or, read OpenSSL's [NOTES.UNIX](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES.UNIX). Or, read OpenSSL's [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) wiki page.

Comment: Oracle no longer produces security fixes for Solaris 11.2, so there's probably more vulnerabilities than just those three.  You should update to Solaris 11.3 and install the latest support updates to that if you really want to be secure.

Answer (score 2):

If you roll your own updates, just how do you plan on finding out when the next critical vulnerability that you need to fix immediately is published?  I suspect you haven't even thought that far ahead.

The proper solution for your problem is to update your OS installation with the latest patches.

Just because a version of, for example. OpenSSL on Solaris is listed as "vulnerable" by some scanner does not mean that the version that comes with the OS is actually vulnerable. OS vendors provide updates that address security issues.  Oracle does it, Red Hat does it.

If you try to overwrite OS-supplied versions with home-grown ones, you do four things:

1. Violate any support contracts.
2. Likely break things.  If you overwrite the OS-supplied Apache binaries, for example, any OS component dependent upon those binaries might be broken.
3. Become stuck with "rolling your own" for the life of the system.  You built your own OpenSSL?  Great.  Now when the next critical zero-day vulnerability is published, you have to drop everything, rebuild OpenSSL, integrate it, test it, and install it.
4. Assume all liability for security problems stemming from using your own home-grown installed software.  You missed that vulnerability published three months ago over a holiday and didn't rebuild your entire software stack?  Your fault.

If you just want to create your own software stack in, say, `/usr/local`, it's not as simple as you think.  You wind up stuck with that maintenance requirement for the life of your system, and you're going to be liable for failing to address any issues.

It will *not* be less expensive in dollars and manhours to make your own installations of Apache and OpenSSL, because you don't get to just do it once.  You have to monitor vulnerability reports at all times and download fixes, rebuild your if critical vulnerability crops up.  And it's not just download and build.  You have to **integrate** the products, too.  Things don't "just work" when you download source code off the internet.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to give a complete answer.I am very familiar with RedHat/CentoS , Ubuntu but never tried anything in Solaris.I will speak to my Tech Lead and get back to you.

Comment: Also can you please explain me how to update the OS safely?https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54816/gmgim.html in this article I did not understand  (2.b)

Comment: @jww *Users have to pay them to fix their broken shit* And spending how many hours downloading, building, testing, and installing a home-rolled software stack is **FREE**?  And it's **FREE** to keep up with vulnerabilities *all the time* in case there's a zero-day published that you have to fix **now**?  "I'll just update the software and it's done."  **No, it's not**.  Once you roll your own, it's never done - it's almost a full-time job just keeping up-to-date.  And FWIW, Solaris is a lot less broken than Linux.  Read the Linux `pwrite` man page, or look at Linux `AUTH_SYS` source code.

Comment: @sharonsahadevan *Also can you please explain me how to update the OS safely?*  Do you have a test system?  Back it up, and see what happens if you run `pkg update` as root.  What you really need to do is figure out if it's cheaper to get a support contract so you can get patches from Oracle, or if you want to assume the responsibility and the ongoing costs of maintaining your own software.  You're likely going to be just fine with `pkg update` unless you have real sensitive data you're protecting.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Thank you. I have a testbed server with the same configuration.I will test the OS upgrade in the testbed and proceed to production server.

Comment: One of the really cool features of the Solaris packaging system is that you can create new Boot Environments (BEs) enabling quick roll back to your current known-working system in the event that testing shows problems  with your app. `pkg update --be-name mumble list-of-packages`.